# How to replace hyperlink text in PDF using itext

Tags: pdf, itext

I need to replace a particular hyperlink in multiple PDF pages which has images, links, paragraph texts, etc. I am able to change the annotations but not the corresponding link text. Here's the code so far

```
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
PdfArray array = reader.getPageN(i).getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS); 
if (array == null) continue;
for (int j = 0; j < array.size(); j++) {        
    PdfDictionary annot = array.getAsDict(j);
    PdfDictionary link = (PdfDictionary)reader.getPdfObjectRelease(annot);
    if(i==1 && j==0 || i==2 && j==0 || i==3 && j==0 || i==4 && j==0 || i==4 && j==1){
        link.put(PdfName.A, new PdfAction(newurl));
    }
}
}
```

I have tried replacing the link text using the below code but it doesn't seem to be present in the stream bytes.

```
PdfObject object = dict.getDirectObject(PdfName.CONTENTS);
if (object instanceof PRStream) {
    PRStream stream = (PRStream)object;
    byte[] data = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
    stream.setData(new String(data).replace(oldstring, newstring).getBytes());
}
```

Also, the link text underline has to be retained

Comment: You can find the text location using text extraction mechanisms, then cover the original link with a white rectangle (or remove it using pdf cleanup), and eventually write the new link at the position.

Comment: I was able to locate the text and cover but the annotation under it does not get removed completely. Tried using `link.remove(PdfName.A);`

Comment: Can you please help me with code

Comment: *locate the text and cover but the annotation under it does not get removed completely* - pdf annotations are **over** the page content, not under. Thus, you'll also have to edit the annotation appearance.

Comment: *help me with code* - I can try on Monday or Tuesday in office.

Comment: That been said, the solution I mean cannot reflow the text the link is part of, merely remove the existing link and paste the new link in the gap. To make this work, both links should have approximately the same length, in particular the new one should not be much longer.

Comment: Ok.. it worked!! Thank you.. I used Rectangle fill to cover up the old content, Chunk for new url text (with same length as that of old url along with text underline) which I appended to Phrase (as I had to add some more content around the link text) and filled the gap using `ColumnText.showTextAligned()`

Comment: Great! Please make that (with some more details if possible) an actual answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code worked for me where I had to change hyperlinks appearing at the same location in multiple pages

```
Chunk url = new Chunk(new_url_text);
url.setUnderline(0.1f, -2f);        
BaseColor bcolor = new BaseColor(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
Font ffont = new Font();
ffont.setColor(0, 114, 53);
ffont.setSize(12);
Phrase p = new Phrase("",ffont);    // Text that appears before the link can be added here (optional)
p.add(url); 
int pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
for (int j = 1; j <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); j++) {
    PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.getOverContent(j);
    canvas.setColorFill(bcolor);
    canvas.rectangle(270, 135, 500, 40);
    canvas.fill();          
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, p, 340, 160, 0);
}
```